# Añadir funciones en un unico listener Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Estoy intentando añadir dos funciones dentro de un mismo listener para poder combinar dos valores de un combo con dos campos deshabilitados y que se habiliten dependiendo del valor que elija.Este es el listener que he creado:

```
 listeners: {
         render: function() {
             var pago = this;
                pago.onChangeCuentasFn();
                pago.onChangeFormaPagoFn();
        }
}
```

Y estas son las funciones a las que llama el listener:

```
onChangeFormaPagoFn: function(combo, record, index) {
    var iban = Ext.getCmp('clieIban');
    iban.clearInvalid();
    if (record.data.codigo == 4) {
        iban.setDisabled(false);
    } else {
        iban.setDisabled(true);
    }
},

onChangeCuentasFn: function(combo, record, index) {
    var cuenta = Ext.getCmp('clieCuentas');
    cuenta.clearInvalid();
    if (record.data.codigo == 3) {
        cuenta.setDisabled(false);
    } else {
        cuenta.setDisabled(true);
    }
},
```

¿Tengo que añadir addListener o jugar con funciones dentro del listener?

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo la razón por la que desea tener ese código divido en 2 funciones distintas. Podrías usar condiciones `if - else` o bien un `switch` ya que ambas realizan la misma operativa y lo único que varía entre ellas es el objeto que modifican. También te quedaría el código mucho más claro y mantenible.

No obstante, entiendo que cuando dices "Estoy intentando añadir dos funciones dentro de un mismo listener" debe ser porque no te está entrando en ambas funciones. Me parece que podría ser por la forma en que has escrito la llamada a dichas funciones. Dentro de un listener si, pero también dentro de un renderer (¿por qué?)

¿Has probado a **no** llamarlas dentro del `renderer`?

Si realmente necesitas que el resultado de estas funciones **modifique** el valor de alguna celda de alguna columna, deberías especificar mejor todo tu problema.

Con los datos aportados no queda claro cual es exactamente tu problema y así no podemos ayudarte.